# Alter text size to fit button width in html

Tags: html, css

Is their any way in html or css to change the text size in order to fit it with in the button of whose width changes according to container. I have 3 buttons of same width, the 3rd text is a little small and its 2 letters will go out of the button if the button shrinks.

Comment: Please post your *code* here first, only then anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible via HTML + CSS. You could only add some JavaScript timer to trace button width and auto adjust text size, then it changes.

Also, you may add some detailed [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change button style on different page size.

Answer (score 0):

SVG can help here. Consider the following:

```
<button style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px; ">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
    <text y="50%" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20">FOOBAR</text>
  </svg>
</button>
```

The `20` in `font-size="20"` refers to coordinates as specified by `viewBox`, so the font size will be 1/5 (20/100) of the size of the button. Of course, this does not precisely solve your problem of ensuring that the text fits in the button, but if you have a general idea of the number of characters, you can choose font size such that that number of characters is likely to fit.

[image]